# Python : change datetime format

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have this Pandas dataframe:

[image]

I want to change date format from "%d/%m/%y" to "%m/%d/%y"

```
all_data["Date demande1"]=all_data["Date demande"].apply(lambda x: datetime.strftime(pd.to_datetime(x), "%m/%d/%Y"))
```

I tried this function, it works with certain lines and others not ??

[image]

Comment: What I see is inconsistency in your data. index 2, 4 and 5 cannot possibly be m/d/y and hence the month and date got switched switched.

Could it be that your column 'Date Demande' has some dates in m/d/y format and some in d/m/y?

Comment: `df['date'].dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')` ?

Comment: the format of 'Date demande' is '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M' - that is for example not the default if you let `pandas` parse this (month comes first by default). as @Datanovice commented, simply use `all_data["Date demande1"]=all_data["Date demande"].dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')` to get a column of strings formatted as you want, assuming `all_data["Date demande"]` is a column of type datetime.

Comment: @GauravAgarwal it could not be true cause it saved automatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
all_data["Date demande1"]=all_data["Date demande"].apply(lambda x: datetime.strftime(pd.to_datetime(x, format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M", errors='ignore'), "%m/%d/%Y"))
```

Comment: Thanks but i tried it and it gives me an error " ValueError: unconverted data remains:  "

Comment: add `errors='ignore'` as an argument to `to_datetime()` function

Comment: it doesn't work too "TypeError: descriptor 'strftime' requires a 'datetime.date' object but received a 'str'"